# ngrx store selector gives 'map is not defined' error

Tags: angular, rxjs, ngrx

With store state of 'regions' properly loaded when I select store for a region with a specific region id I get the error:

core.js:1542 ERROR ReferenceError: map is not defined
    at SafeSubscriber.selectedRegion$.subscribe.region [as _next] (eval at push../src/app/pages/milestones/management/milestone.component.ts.MilestoneManagementComponent.onRegionChanged (milestone.component.ts:58)

selector.ts

```
export const selectRegionsState = createFeatureSelector<RegionsState>('regions');

export const selectRegion = (regionId: number) => createSelector(
  selectRegionsState,
  regionsState => regionsState.entities[regionId]
);
```

reducer.ts

```
export interface RegionsState extends EntityState<Region> {
  allRegionsLoaded: boolean;
}

export const regionsAdapter: EntityAdapter<Region> = createEntityAdapter<Region>();

export const initialRegionsState: RegionsState = regionsAdapter.getInitialState({
  allRegionsLoaded: false
});

export function regionsReducer(state = initialRegionsState, action: RegionActions): RegionsState {
...
}
```

component.ts

```
selectedRegion$: Observable<Region> = of({ id: 0, codeName: '', text: 'Select Region'});
...

onRegionChanged(regionId: number): void {
    this.selectedRegion$ = this.store.select(selectRegion(regionId));
}

export function regionsReducer(state = initialRegionsState, action: RegionActions): RegionsState {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had to cast undefined object to the type Observable is expecting.

```
selectedRegion$: Observable<Region> = of(<Region>{ id: 0, codeName: '', text: 'Select Region'});
```